# ExportAsFixedFileFormat is suddenly not exporting images and formatting from the Excel Document Any ideas?

Tags: excel, vb.net

The method ExportAsFixedFormat in Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel is no longer exporting any graphics or formatting to the PDF file. The code has not changed.

This method worked in my development debug environment as recently as July 9th 2019 using the Interop Library (version 15) in Visual Studio 2017.

It also worked as recently as July 16th in the production environment using an installation of Office 2013, and has been working in Production since April.

I'm building a report in Excel with Charts, a logo.jpg image and I am formatting column widths, row heights, and adding thickened borders around some of the cells. This is all saved in an Excel document first and then exported to PDF using the method above.

When I was asked to manually generate the report for a new client on July 23rd, I determined that the above charts, the image and the formatting were all excluded from the output in the PDF, although the data and font changes were exported. It's pretty ugly though.

So far...

I confirmed that it is no longer working in either environment (Development or Production) so whatever changed not only changed the office 2013 installation, but the Interop library in Visual Studio. (MS Update maybe?)

I tried downgrading the library to version 14 (instead of 15), and then tried upgrading it to 15.4795.1000 and neither of those work.

Manually using SaveAs from within Excel 2013 has the same result, but not really a valid test because I never tried it manually in the first place.

I searched for documentation on Microsoft updates, they did update Excel 2013 to fix two remote code execution vulnerabilities, but I'm not sure where to look that would tell me that the method ExportAsFixedFileFormat was changed and now requires "X". Although I did re-read the docs on the method to see if I was missing anything.

I wasn't using XLFixedFormatQuality, but added it just in case and that had no impact on the issue.

The Code is fairly straightforward and as mentioned, it was working just fine, it still exports and creates a PDF file, the file is just text data only though and only the Font Formatting made it through the export.

```
xlWorkBook.ExportAsFixedFormat(Excel.XlFixedFormatType.xlTypePDF, ParamValues(3), Excel.XlFixedFormatQuality.xlQualityStandard)
```

The Filename is stored in ParamValues(3).

There are no errors, no exceptions generated, with the exception of a loss of formatting, charts and images in the final product, the application behaves just as it always has.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further speculation and testing, we determined that it was printer driver related. I had installed a generic text/only printer to test something I had been working on and Win10 was set to "manage" my default printer by setting my default to whatever printer I most recently used.

Using RDP into the production machine was bringing this default printer with me into the setting and the Export method was using that printer driver to generate the PDF